# Помогите с правилом XSLT

Tags: xslt

Имеется XML.

```
<file>
  <section>
    <comment>#   Секция заслешивания путей без слеша в конце</comment>
    <rule typename="RewriteRule" pattern="/([-a-zA-Z]+)" substitution="/$1/" flags="R=301,L" />
    <rule typename="RewriteRule" pattern="/([-a-zA-Z]+)/([-a-zA-Z]+)" substitution="/$1/$2/" flags="R=301,L" />
    <rule typename="RewriteRule" pattern="/([-a-zA-Z]+)/([-a-zA-Z]+)/([-a-zA-Z]+)" substitution="/$1/$2/$3/" flags="R=301,L" />
  </section>
  <section>
    <comment>#    Секция преобразования URL в вызов контроллера</comment>
  </section>
</file>
```

На выходе после преобразования, получаем следующий текстовый документ.

```
#   Секция заслешивания путей без слеша в конце

RewriteRule ^/([-a-zA-Z]+)/([-a-zA-Z]+)/([-a-zA-Z]+)$ /$1/$2/$3/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/([-a-zA-Z]+)/([-a-zA-Z]+)$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/([-a-zA-Z]+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

#    Секция преобразования URL в вызов контроллера
```

Имеем следующий шаблон для работы с узлами `rule`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- шаблон сопоставления с узлом rule -->
    <xsl:template match="rule">     
        <!-- Если у узла rule есть хотябы узел типа и он не пустой -->
        <xsl:if test="@typename != ''">
            <!-- Выведем переход строки -->
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <!-- Выведем из текущего узла тип правила -->
            <xsl:value-of select="@typename"></xsl:value-of>
            <!-- Начинаем паттерн с сопоставления с началом строки -->
            <xsl:text> ^</xsl:text>
            <!-- Выведем сам паттерн -->
            <xsl:value-of select="@pattern"></xsl:value-of>
            <!-- Завершим сопостовлением с концом строки -->
            <xsl:text>$ </xsl:text>

            <!-- Выведем правило подстановки -->
            <xsl:value-of select="@substitution"></xsl:value-of>

            <!-- Если есть свойство флагов и оно не пустое -->
            <xsl:if test="@flags != ''">
                <!-- Начнем выводить блок флагов -->            
                <xsl:text> [</xsl:text>
                <!-- Выведем влаги -->
                <xsl:value-of select="@flags"></xsl:value-of>
                <!-- Завершаем вывод флагов -->
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>              
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Вопрос, как доработать шаблон, что бы он в каждом паттерне, убирал первый слэш из строк типа `^/([-a-zA-Z]+)$` и паттерн выглядел бы так `^([-a-zA-Z]+)$`

Comment: Не забудьте указать `<xsl:output method="text" />`, чтобы он не начал экранировать спец.символы где не надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя функции для работы с текстом `substring()` или `substring-after()`. `substring()` возвращает подстроку из исходной строки, начиная с указанной позиции, а `substring-after()` возвращает подстроку после указанного символа

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(@pattern, 2)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@pattern, '/')"/>
```

Comment: Я делаю только первые шаги в XSLT и ответ не дал мне понять как действовать далее....

Comment: что именно непонятно? Просто замените Ваш вызов <xsl:value-of select="@pattern"/>` на любой мой.

Comment: хорошо понял спасибо. Нет ли у вас под рукой ссылочки на хороший справочник по XSLT, желательно на русском, если такой есть.

Comment: Две дублирующихся ссылки. Одна на MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256069(v=vs.120).aspx вторая на W3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp. На MSDN доступен машинный (весьма адекватный) перевод на русский